Would the use of LIPC's for Lasers avoid eye damage for bystanders?
Laser Induced Plasma Channels (LIPC) can create a tunnel of plasma in the air for a brief moment (milliseconds). But the formation of a LIPC is a process and not something instantaneous when it comes to a perspective in milliseconds, the first thing to move are the electrons, then the ions.
And there are a lot of ways of using an LIPC when it comes to high power lasers (like laser weaponry that uses 10 kilojoules/kilowatts or even more), you could use it to make a plasma lense to refocus the laser in certain points of its path.
However, I was wondering if it would be possible to use the plasma channel to avoid bystanders from suffering eye damage in case such a powerful laser is used.

It doesn't sound like it would work. For one thing, plasmas produce UV and Xray light. Not very protective.
